# Drag and drop not working in Selenium 3.0

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying the below code to test drag and drop in Selenium 3.0 and find that code is not working, meaning that it's not showing any error and also not providing expected result.

I have tried the same code in selenium 2.53 and it's working . Kindly someone review my code for the same and let me know if I missed something.

**Selenium 3.0**

**Browser : Mozilla 2.52**

```
package dynamicXpath;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;   
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;  
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;  
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Action;  
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class refermeprobI {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");

     FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
      profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);      
      WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);


            driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


    driver.get("https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop");

    Actions act = new Actions(driver);

    WebElement src = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column-a']"));
    WebElement dst = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column-b']"));






   act.dragAndDrop(src, dst).build().perform();

   System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='column-b']/header")).getText());



}

}
```

Comment: I don't see any error in your code as such. But I'm still not sure about your Mozilla Firefox version & geckodriver version. Drag & drop worked well for me with Selenium 3.x.

Comment: which version of geckodriver are you using?

Comment: I can see `setEnableNativeEvents(true)` being depreciated. Still able to use that?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following:

```
 act.clickAndHold(src).moveToElement(dst).release(src).build().perform();
```

This works in certain scenarios where `dragAndDrop()` doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code. Everything is fine except if you use Selenium 3.0.0 then need to set Desired Capabilities. I've also checked your code with Selenium latest 3.4. If you use Selenium 3.4 then you don't need to set Desired Capabilities. I used Firefox 52. 
I hope that this info will help you to understand the problem you have encountered.
Thanks